# Converting Non-Time String into HH:MM

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a Cell range that contains data in the following format:

```
1d 12h 37m
```

All Data is in this format but ranges from single to double digit values.

I need to try to convert this data as an ultimate goal into purely `hh:mm`

I am struggling with the conversion of this. The main issue arises when the number of digits varying between double and single digits.

I have the formula to extrapolate purely the numbers and remove the letters from this:

```
=SUM(ROUND(MOD(SMALL(IFERROR(ROW(OFFSET(A$1,,,LEN(A11)))+MID(A11,1+LEN(A11)-ROW(OFFSET(A$1,,,LEN(A11))),1)%, LEN(A11)+1), ROW(OFFSET(A$1,,,SUM(N(ISNUMBER(0+MID(A11,ROW(OFFSET(A$1,,,LEN(A11))),1))))))),1)*100,0)*(10^(ROW(OFFSET(A$1,,,SUM(N(ISNUMBER(0+MID(A11,ROW(OFFSET(A$1,,,LEN(A11))),1))))))-1)))&""
```

Ideally this needs to all be done as a formula but a VBA script is okay.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to convert the days into hours as well? Do you need the cumulative total in hours if days are also needed?

Comment: Solution provided does the job perfectly. Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula to change to date/time:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("d",A1)-1),0)+TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("d",A1)+1,1),LEN(A1)),"h ",":"),"m",""))
```

Then either format it `[hh]:mm` which will return `36:37` or `hh:mm` which will return `12:37`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXT(((LEFT(A2,FIND("d",A2)-1))+((TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("d",A2)+1,FIND("h",A2)-FIND("d",A2)-1)))+((TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("h",A2)+1,FIND("m",A2)-FIND("h",A2)-1)))/60))/24),"[h]:mm")
```

This formula assumes a couple things:
"d", "h", "m" will always be present
You need Days converted to Hours

Explanation:

Days:

```
=(LEFT(A2,FIND("d",A2)-1))
```

Hours:

```
=(TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("d",A2)+1,FIND("h",A2)-FIND("d",A2)-1)))
```

Minutes:

```
=(TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("h",A2)+1,FIND("m",A2)-FIND("h",A2)-1)))
```

Combining:

```
=TEXT((<days>+(<hours>+(<minutes>/60))/24),"[h]:mm")
```

If you want it without Days converted to Hours, change "[h]:mm" to "hh:mm".

Comment: @scottcraner 's answer is better in every way.